# Find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a|x|)^n}{\frac{n}{2}!}$ where $\frac{n}{2}!=\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Find A=$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a|x|)^n}{\frac{n}{2}!}$
where $\frac{n}{2}!=\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)$.

I know that A converges (I used the ratio test) but I can't work out what it converges to.

Eventually, I want to show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty A dx$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve it, through the calculus of the derivative:

\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\pgamma}[1]{\Gamma\left(#1\right)}
S(X)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{X^n}{\pgamma{\frac n2+1}}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{X^n}{\pgamma{\frac n2+1}}
\\\frac{dS}{dX}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nX^{n-1}}{\pgamma{\frac n2+1}}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\frac n2 X^{n-1}}{\pgamma{\frac n2+1}}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{X^{n-1}}{\pgamma{\frac n2}}
\\&=\frac2{\pgamma{\frac12}}+2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{X^{n-1}}{\pgamma{\frac n2}}=\frac2{\pgamma{\frac12}}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{X^{n+1}}{\pgamma{\frac{n+2}2}}
\\&=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}+2X\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{X^n}{\pgamma{\frac n2+1}}=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}+2X\,S(X)
\end{align*}

$$\frac{dS}{dX}-2X\,S(X)=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\quad\text{(first order linear ODE)}$$

$$S(X)=\exp(X^2)\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int\exp(-X^2)\,dX=(\operatorname{erf}X+C)\exp(X^2)$$

$$S(0)=1\implies C=1\implies S(X)=(\operatorname{erf}X+1)\exp(X^2)$$

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a|x|)^n}{\pgamma{\frac n2+1}}=\big(\operatorname{erf}(a|x|)+1\big)\exp(a^2 x^2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Ask Wolfram Alpha and get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{(\frac{n}{2})!} = \big(\mathrm{erf}(z)+1\big) e^{z^2}$$
and it tells you that the integral 
$$\int_{0}^\infty\big(\mathrm{erf}(z)+1\big) e^{z^2} dz$$
does not converge.

Comment: Why do you consider this integral : $\int_{0}^\infty\big(\mathrm{erf}(z)+1\big) e^{z^2} dz$ instead of $\int_{0}^\infty\ z^udu/(u/2)!$ The variable for summation is not $z$ but $n$

Comment: @JJacquelin: Because it is part of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty A dx$, and it is **this**
integral what should 'eventually' be tested for convergence, and **not** the
transition of the sum to an integral.