# Calculating a series of a factorial of a rational number.

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

Is there any standard procedure for solving sums of factorials of rational numbers? I would like to see how to solve $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k/2)!}$. According to Wolfram, this series converges and I would like to check it step by step. Thank you.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k/2)!}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{((2m+1)/2)!}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{((2m)/2)!}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(m+3/2)}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!}$

Comment: For the sum containing the gamma function you will need $_1F_1(1;3/2;1)$ function and its relation to the error function $\operatorname{erf}z$.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson. It is simpler than that. Cheers, stranger !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Simpler than breaking the series up into even and odd terms? Please tell.

Comment: See [Find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a|x|)^n}{\frac{n}{2}!}$ where $\frac{n}{2}!=\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691140/find-sum-n-0-infty-fracaxn-fracn2-where-fracn2-gamma)